# Netbeans - Java Excel NullPointerExcepetion

Tags: java, excel

I'm having a problem with writing in a excel file. I'm using Apache POI to write on the excel.

My code is:

```
private void EscreverExcel(String Nome) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{
    File src = new File("D:\\Work\\Fortune\\DadosCliente.xlsx");

    FileInputStream fist = new FileInputStream(src);
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(fist);
    XSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    sheet.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue(Nome);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(src);
    wb.write(fos);
    wb.close();
}
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
   Excel ex = new Excel();
   ex.EscreverExcel("Mário");
}
```

and when i run the program they give me this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

at fortunewheel.Excel.EscreverExcel(Excel.java:79)
at fortunewheel.Excel.main(Excel.java:87)
```

What i did wrong? can u help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: which line is line no. 79?

Comment: The line 79 is: "sheet.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue(Nome);" and the 87 is: "ex.EscreverExcel("Mário");"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said, line no. 79 is the following line.

```
sheet.getRow(0).createCell(2).setCellValue(Nome);
```

My guess is, either `sheet` is a null object or, `sheet.getRow()` is returning null. I suggest you to check both of them to avoid null pointer exception.

> From official documentation of [XSSFSheet.getRow()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFSheet.html#getRow(int)):

`getRow()` method returns the logical row ( 0-based). If you ask for a row that is not defined you get a null. This is to say row 4 represents the fifth row on a sheet.

Parameters:

```
rownum - row to get
```

Returns:

```
XSSFRow representing the rownumber or null if its not defined on the sheet
```

So my guess is, `getRow()` is returning null in your case.

Comment: getRow(0) is returning null

Answer (score 0):

OK, please check sheet.getRow(0) is not equal to null.

Comment: Sheet.getRow(0) is null

Comment: so that's why you have NPE